# RecyclerView item height and gravity not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, height, gravity, horizontal-recyclerview

I have a problem with item height and gravity in a horizontal recyclerview as you can see in the picture: [RecyclerView item height and gravity not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I5o4.png)

How to set the item height to same height as recyclerciew and the gravity at the bottom of recyclerview ?

Thank you for your help.

My code for Activity_Drill_Graph.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Drill_Graph_Activity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_drill_graph"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_drill_graph" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_5dp"
                android:background="@color/grey"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="100">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="@color/lightgrey"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView10"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/_10"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView9"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/_9"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/_8"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/_7"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/_6"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/_5"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/_4"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/_3"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/_2"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/_1"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView0"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/_0"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/date"
                        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewDrillGraph"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_5dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="@dimen/padding_5dp"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

item code: drill_graph_single_column.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/lightgrey"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_1dp"
    android:weightSum="110">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSkill"
        style="@style/btnStyleScoreGrey"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="@string/skill"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDate"
        style="@style/btnStyleDrillGraphGrey"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_1dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:text="@string/date"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My code for RecyclerView Adapter:

```
package org.poolshot.poolshotacademy;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.util.List;

public class My_DrillGraph_RecyclerView_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<My_DrillGraph_RecyclerView_Adapter.MyHolder> {
    SharedPreferences defaultPreferencesSettings;
    private Context myRCAContext;
    private List<String> myDrillGraphDates;
    private List<Integer> myDrillGraphSkill;

    // constructor
    public My_DrillGraph_RecyclerView_Adapter(Context applicationContext, List<String> mDrillGraphDates, List<Integer> mDrillGraphSkill) {
        this.myRCAContext = applicationContext;
        this.myDrillGraphDates = mDrillGraphDates;
        this.myDrillGraphSkill = mDrillGraphSkill;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        View layout = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drill_graph_single_column,null);
        MyHolder myHolder = new MyHolder(layout);
        return myHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        String skill = myDrillGraphSkill.get(position).toString();
        // set color for buttons
        viewHolder.btnDate.setBackground(myRCAContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_btn_grey));
        viewHolder.btnSkill.setTextColor(myRCAContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        // set text for buttons
        viewHolder.btnDate.setText(myDrillGraphDates.get(position));
        viewHolder.btnSkill.setText(skill);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myDrillGraphDates.size();
    }

    public static class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        Button btnDate;
        Button btnSkill;

        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            btnDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
            btnSkill = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnSkill);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please share a picture/draw of desired view.

Comment: The link of the picture is in the original post. we clearly see the position and height of the items. their background color is different than the recyclerview. the items should be at bottom of the recyclerview and has match_parent height.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution : 
I changed the code of the class MyHolder as :

```
public static class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Button btnDate;
    Button btnSkill;

    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        btnDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
        btnSkill = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnSkill);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
}
```